# Existence of the Differential of a multi-variable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, partial-derivative

I am trying to understand the concept of differential of multi-variable functions with which I have the following function:

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{2x^2-y^2}{x^2+2y^2} & (x,y) \ne (0,0) \\
5 & (x,y) = (0,0)
\end{array}\right.
$$

Whay I have done is, to find the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial{x}}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial{y}}$ of the function for $(x,y) \ne (0.0)$ then, find the alternated limits $\lim_{x\to0}{(\lim_{y \to 0}{(\frac{2x^2-y^2}{x^2+2y^2})})}$ and $\lim_{y\to0}{(\lim_{x \to 0}{(\frac{2x^2-y^2}{x^2+2y^2})})}$ and once they exist, compare them and if they are equal then the function is differentiable at the point $(0,0)$?

Would that be enough to prove that the function is differentiable at the point? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is not continuous at the origin and thus is not differentiable there. The way I first saw this was by enforcing the change of variables
$$
(x,y)\mapsto \left(r\cos \theta,\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}\sin\theta\right)
$$
Then your limit becomes
$$
\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{2r^2\cos\theta-\frac{r^2}{2}\sin^2\theta}{r^2}\\
=2\cos\theta-\frac{1}{2}\sin^2\theta
$$
as we shrink the ellipses major and minor radii to $0$,
which is not independent of $\theta$, as is required for continuity.

However, if this makes you uncomfortable, it might be easier to take $y=x$ and find the limit at $0$ is $1/3$ while instead, if $y=x^2$, the limit is $2$.

Comment: how did you come about the $\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: It is a convenient change of coordinates. Namely it makes the denominator just $r^2$. Like I said, if this part doesn't make sense, feel feee to use the latter half of the answer which is more standard

Comment: I left it up because I think it is a good technique but I don't want to cause more confusion :)